# I have a picker that does not return the selected item

Tags: swiftui-list, swift-data

```
@Query(sort: \roleModel.role) var roles: [roleModel]
@State var selectedRole = ""

var body: some View {
   `VStsck`
        `Text("You selected: \(selectedRole)") // Display the selected role here`
        `HStack {`
    Picker(" ", selection: $selectedRole) {
    ForEach(roles, id: \.self) { role in
    Text(role.role)
    }
    }
    }
    }
}
```